# Accessing mongodb data on aws instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, pymongo

Due to some hardware issue my aws instance stopped functioning. Team suggested me to stop and and start the instanace.

Now aws provided new IP, where all data is present. I installed mongodb and had couple of databases there.

Now when I checked on new server mongodb was not working. I started mongod and letter I asked to create `/data/db` directory. Now mongodb is functioning but when I do

`"show databases"` none of my previous database appearning. Any help on getting this data back.?

Comment: check your EBS volumes. If your data was in the ephemeral disk you lost it.
If you still have a EBS not attached to any instance your data could be there.

Comment: @ViniciusZaramella: Thanks a lot. Could you please guide how do I check EBS volumes

Comment: I checked http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html but no information regarding how to check

Comment: In the aws web console go to EC2 services > Elastic Block Storage > Volumes. Check if there is any Volume there.

Answer (score 3):

A AWS EC2 instance have two types of Storage. A Ephemeral storage and a EBS Volume storage.

The Ephemeral storage should be used for temporary data only. If you restart your EC2 the data in it will not be lost, but if you stop and restart you loose it all. When trying to stop a EC2 AWS gives you this message.

> Note that when your instances are stopped: Any data on the ephemeral
>   storage of your instances will be lost.

This kind of storage is provisioned very close to the instance and because of that it is faster.

EBS is a persistent storage independent of your EC2 instance. It can be attached/dettached from your EC2. This is the kind of storage you want to use when creating a database inside your instance.

Comment: there is volume there at  EC2 services > Elastic Block Storage > Volumes, with status okay

Comment: Now you have to check inside your EC2 instance and access this volume in order to verify if the database data is there.

Comment: Another option is, if you created a AMI from your EC2, the data that was there in the moment of the operation is still inside the AMI.
If none of this options solve your problem you probably lost your data. 

If you still studying how to manage a database inside AWS EC2 you should use a service like https://compose.io/ to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: thanks a ton. Inside EC2-instance where do I check, if you can assist